# Is it possible to dynamically generate a self extracting executable but only sign it once at the beginning?

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

My server needs to generate a client whose `app.config` needs to be altered dynamically during run time, based on information that the user submits. This then needs to be compressed into a single executable (so either all the external `dll` and resources need to be embedded into the executable or I need to create a self extracting executable). However, I also must sign it with my company's certificate, but I will not have access to the certificate on server run time (aka dynamic client generation time), and only have access to it at client compile time (essentially). Is what I'm asking for even possible to accomplish, and if so are there any pointers to how I could do this? 
I was able to create self extracting executable via `7zip`, but it brings up security prompts on windows and anti virus programs since it's not signed.

The client is a .net 4.0 winforms app (cannot be changed).

Comment: "... app.config needs to be altered dynamically during runtime, based on information that the user submits". Sounds like the best solution is to find another way to store/update data, like a different file and/or a database. Or, use the user settings which are fine to be modified.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by user settings? This is a small application so using a database would not be preferable..

Comment: You can find some info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) but re-reading your question I'm not so sure it would help. So, your use case is to deploy the app, have a user make some selections, and then re-deploy the app? Why? Maybe if you can tell us what it is the user is changing, we can help you find a better solution. I understand it's a small app, but there are lightweight database solutions out there... You're looking at a complex use-case which might require a complex solution.

Comment: Basically, a user inputs some basic personal info in an online webpage, which is submitted to our server. This personal information needs to be displayed in the executable client (along with a few other fields that will be unique per exe), meaning our server will need to generate a unique exe per valid request. The user will then be able to download this executable (we provide the executable from our server).

Comment: and it has to be displayed when? Why can't you pull the information from the server once the client is running?

Comment: Not all the information can be pulled from server, as it is also used as a soft check for unique identification via client to server communication (required as told by higher ups).

Comment: If an executable could be modified after it was signed and the signature was still trusted, that would defeat the entire point of signing.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the config file or use some other method to persist settings, you can also embed resources using Msbuild but I really don't believe you can sign something without the certificate!

Comment: *I really don't believe you can sign something without the certificate* - If not for this, what reason would anyone have for signing anything?

Comment: What I wanted to say here is that even with whatever info you may have about the certificate let's say because the exe that is running is signed with it, still you need the certificate so yes you are right.

Comment: Of course.  I assumed the last sentence of your answer was intended to be a bit tongue-in-cheek anyways.  ;)

Comment: Sorry but English is not my native language. Now I have to look up tongue-in-cheek is some slang dictionary. :)